# Member not zeroed, a clang++ bug?

Tags: c++, c++11, clang, clang++

Consider the following code:

```
class A {
public:
    int i;
    A() {}
};

class B {
public:
    A a;
    int i;
};

int main() {
    B* p = new B {};
    std::cout << p->i << " " << p->a.i << "\n";
}
```

Compiled with -std=c++11 in clang++, `p->i` turns out to be zero, but `p->a.i` doesn't.  Shouldn't the whole object be zeroed as long as its class doesn't have user-provided constructor?

EDIT: Since there are some extensive discussion in the comments, I think it's better to add some excerpt from the standard here:

> To value-initialize an object of type `T` means:
>
> - if `T` is a (possibly cv-qualified) class type (Clause 9) with a user-provided constructor (12.1), then the default constructor for T is called (and the initialization is ill-formed if `T` has no accessible default constructor);
> - if `T` is a (possibly cv-qualified) non-union class type without a user-provided constructor, then the object is zero-initialized and, if `T`’s implicitly-declared default constructor is non-trivial, that constructor is called.
> - if `T` is an array type, then each element is value-initialized;
> - otherwise, the object is zero-initialized.
>
> To zero-initialize an object or reference of type T means:
>
> - if `T` is a scalar type (3.9), the object is set to the value `0` (zero), taken as an integral constant expression, converted to `T`;
> - if `T` is a (possibly cv-qualified) non-union class type, each non-static data member and each base-class subobject is zero-initialized and padding is initialized to zero bits;
> - if `T` is a (possibly cv-qualified) union type, the object’s first non-static named data member is zero-initialized and padding is initialized to zero bits;
> - if `T` is an array type, each element is zero-initialized;
> - if `T` is a reference type, no initialization is performed.

The second bullet of each applies here.

Comment: But class `A` _does_ have a user-defined constructor.

Comment: @icabod: Shouldn't the zero-initialization of `b` recursively zero-initialize its member `a`?

Comment: No, it shouldn't. In this case, it calls the default constructor, and that does nothing to `A::i`.

Comment: But "zero-initialisation" of `a` in this case means default-constructing it, not filling it with zeros, which for a class could be very much invalid.

Comment: Note that there is no *zero-initialization* of a `B`. There is *value-initialization*.

Comment: @icabod: Shouldn't zero-initialization of an object of a class type simply mean zero-initialize all its non-static data member and base-class subobject (even the padding bits), no matter whether there is user-provided constructor or not?

Comment: @juanchopanza: Yes, it's value-initialization.  But the first step of value-initialization of an object of a class without user-provided constructor is the zero-initialization of the object, right?

Comment: @goodbyeera zero-initialization only makes sense for types that can be zero-initialized. For built-ins, that makes sense. For user defined types, rarely. In your case, the value-initialization of an `A` does not result in a zero initialization of its data members.

Comment: @juanchopanza: zero-initialization for user defined types is simply recursive zero-initialization on all its members.

Comment: @juanchopanza: In my case, the member of type `A` is not value-initialized.  value-initialization isn't recursive while zero-initialization is.

Comment: Value initialization is recursive in this case. `B` is an aggregate, and if you value initialize it, its data members get value-initialized.

Comment: @juanchopanza: `if T is a (possibly cv-qualified) non-union class type without a user-provided constructor, then the object
is zero-initialized and, if T’s implicitly-declared default constructor is non-trivial, that constructor is
called.` - Quote from the standard of the definition of value-initialization.  How could it be recursive?

Comment: No idea, because your quote is out of context.

Comment: @juanchopanza: What context do you need? The quote is from C++11 8.5/7, and specifies how value-initialisation is done for a class like `B` with no default constructor. In particular, "the object is zero-initialised".

Comment: @juanchopanza: I updated the question to add the full quote from the standard.

Comment: @goodbyeera OK, This changed between C++03 and C++11. My answer only applies to C++03: `value initialization: if T is a non-union class type without a user-declared constructor, then every non-static data member and base-class component of T is value-initialized;`. Since you are compiling in C++11 mode, it seems you are right and I was wrong.

Comment: @juanchopanza: Never mind.  I should have included relevant parts of the standard in the first place.

Comment: @goodbyeera No, I should have known better. I made the mistake of assuming this hadn't changed because the compilers I used kept the C++03 behaviour. Anyway, I edited my post.

Comment: @juanchopanza: Looking at the c++03 rule, I got another question.  According to that rule, value-init for a type without a user-declared ctor means memberwise value-init.  That rule doesn't mention a ctor call at all!  Comparing with other rules in the standard, we can see that if a ctor call should be made, then it will be mentioned in the text.  Thus, not mentioning a ctor call means ctor won't be called in that particular case of value-init.  E.g. For `struct {virtual void f() {}};`, it meets the criteria of that rule, then how is the vptr get setup in the process of a c++03 value-init?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Clang is correct, per the C++11 standard plus relevant DRs**

In the original C++11 specification, `B{}` would perform value-initialization, resulting in `a.i` being zero-initialized. This was a change in behavior compared to C++98 for cases like

```
B b = {};
```

... which were handled as aggregate initialization in C++98 but treated as value-initialization in C++11 FDIS.

However, the behavior in this case was changed by [core issue 1301](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1301), which restored the C++98 behavior by mandating that aggregate initialization is used whenever an aggregate is initialized by a *braced-init-list*. Since this issue is considered a DR, it is treated as *de facto* applying to earlier revisions of the C++ standard, so a conforming C++11 compiler would be expected to perform aggregate initialization here rather than value-initialization.

Ultimately, it's a bad idea to rely on value-initialization to initialize your data members, especially for a class that has user-provided constructors.

Comment: This CWG issue 1301 became the motivation for cppreference to start (or at least to agree to start)  merging behavior-changing DRs into the standards they were applied to. http://en.cppreference.com/w/Talk:cpp/language/value_initialization

Answer (score 6):

It does indeed look like a bug (or, as pointed out in the comments, behaving according to C++03 despite specifying C++11). In C++11, value-initialisation should zero the members of `a` before calling its default constructor. Initialisation of `B` is governed by this rule of 8.5/7

> if T is a (possibly cv-qualified) non-union class type without a user-provided constructor, then the object **is zero-initialized** and, if T’s implicitly-declared default constructor is non-trivial, that constructor is called.

The zero-initialisation should recursively zero-initialise `a` per this rule of 8.5/5

> if T is a (possibly cv-qualified) non-union class type, each non-static data member and each base-class subobject is zero-initialized

and, of course, zero-initialisation of `a` should set `i` to zero.

Comment: "without a user-provided constructor" - but A has a user-provided constructor.

Comment: @Suma: Yes, but `B` doesn't so, by the first rule, it should be zero-initialised before calling the constructor. By the second rule, that should recursively zero-initialise `a`.

Comment: Is it not rather an oversight in the standard? When there is a constructor (in A this time), it always needs to be called, it cannot be replaced with zero-initialization. Or should the compiler first zero initialize and then call a constructor? That is not what the standard is saying.

Comment: @Suma: That's exactly what the standard is saying. Everything is zero-initialised; then the implicitly-declared constructor of `B` is called, which in turn calls the constructor of `A`.

Comment: Got it, this changed in C++11. In C++03, value initialization ` if T is a non-union class type without a user-declared constructor, then every non-static data member and base-class component of T is value-initialized;`

Comment: @juanchopanza: Thanks; not a bug as such then, just out-of-date behaviour.

Comment: Take a look at Richard Smith's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23745872/365496) and his references. Clang appears to be correct under the relevant DRs.

Answer (score 5):

It is <strike>not</strike> a compiler bug<strike>, it is a bug in your code</strike>. The compiler seems to be implementing the C++03 behaviour, but this has crucially changed in C++11.

These are some relevant quotes from the C++03 and C++11 standards

In C++03:

> To value-initialize an object of type T means:
>
> — if T is a class type
>   (clause 9) with a user-declared constructor (12.1), then the default
>   constructor for T is called (and the initialization is ill-formed if T
>   has no accessible default constructor);
>
> — **if T is a non-union class
>   type without a user-declared constructor, then every non-static data
>   member and base-class component of T is value-initialized;**

(emphasis mine)

In C++11:

> To value-initialize an object of type T means:
>
> — if T is a (possibly
>   cv-qualified) class type (Clause 9) with a user-provided constructor
>   (12.1), then the default constructor for T is called (and the
>   initialization is ill-formed if T has no accessible default
>   constructor);
>
> — if T is a (possibly cv-qualified) non-union class type
>   without a user-provided constructor, then **the object is
>   zero-initialized** and, if T’s implicitly-declared default constructor
>   is non-trivial, that constructor is called.

and

> To zero-initialize an object or reference of type T means:
>
> — if T is a
>   scalar type (3.9), the object is set to the value 0 (zero), taken as
>   an integral constant expression, converted to T;
>
> - if T is a
>     (possibly cv-qualified) non-union class type, **each non-static data
>     member and each base-class subobject is zero-initialized** and padding
>     is initialized to zero bits;

---

**Note: The following only applies to C++03**:

Either remove `A`'s user-provided constructor, or change it to

```
A() : i() {}
```

When you *value-initialize* a `B` here,

```
B* p = new B {};
```

it *value-initializes* its data members. Since `A` has a default constructor, the value-initialization results in a call to that. But that constructor does not explicitly initialize `A::i`, so it gets *default-initialized*, which for an `int` means no initialization is performed.

If you had not provided a default constructor for `A`, *then* the data member would get zero-initialized when an `A` is value-initialized.

Comment: Take a look at Richard Smith's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23745872/365496) and his references. Clang appears to be correct under the relevant DRs.

Answer (score 0):

Integral types are not required to be initialized to a value like that in a non-default constructor (since you have provided a constructor)

Change your constructor to `A() : i(0) {}`.