# Certain case of value-initialization in C++03 doesn't call constructor?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++03

I actually got the idea of this question when I was discussing on another question of mine ([Member not zeroed, a clang++ bug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21932544/member-not-zeroed-a-clang-bug)).  That question is about C++11 value-initialization, but when I saw the C++03 value-initialization rule someone posted there, I am confused.

The value-initialization rule from C++03 is:

> To value-initialize an object of type T means:
>
> - if T is a class type (clause 9) with a user-declared constructor (12.1), then the default constructor for T is called (and the
>     initialization is ill-formed if T has no accessible default
>     constructor);
> - if T is a non-union class type without a user-declared constructor, then every non-static data member and base-class component of T is
>     value-initialized;
> - if T is an array type, then each element is value-initialized;
> - otherwise, the object is zero-initialized

Please look at the second bullet which defines the value-initialize process for a type without user-declared constructor.  This rule doesn't mention a constructor call.  As we can see from the description of other cases of value-initialize or from the description of default-initialize, if constructor should be called, it will be explicitly mentioned in the text of the standard.  I know there is certain initialization form that constructor doesn't get called (e.g. {}-initialization for aggregates), but should it be the case for value-initialize of `non-union class type without a user-declared constructor`?  The implicitly declared constructor of such a type could easily be non-trivial.  For example:

```
class A {
public:
    virtual void f() {}
};
```

According to the rule in C++03, if the implicitly declared non-trivial constructor doesn't get called in the process of the value-initialization of an object of `A`, how does the vptr of the object get setup?  (I know things related to vptr is all implementation-defined, but this doesn't change the major point I'm trying to make here.)

(Someone would argue that the absence of mentioning a constructor call in the rule doesn't mean constructor won't get called.  OK.  Let's say constructor will get called according to some other rule I may have overlooked, but since all members need to be value-initialized anyway, wouldn't that cause the members' constructors to be called more than once?)

Asking a question for C++03 when it's already C++11 everywhere may seem worthless.  Yeah, that's a valid point.  However, I think I could more or less learn something if I finally figure this out (whether I am wrong and why).

EDIT: Maybe I shouldn't have used vptr as an example. My point is, wouldn't skipping the call to a non-trivial constructor cause some potential problem for the validity of the object?  After all, it's called non-trivial for a reason.

Comment: That standard quote doesn't preclude the compiler from inserting its own *magic* during initialization, and setting up the vtable is part of that magic.

Comment: @Praetorian: Maybe I shouldn't have used vptr as an example. My point is, wouldn't skipping the call to a non-trivial constructor cause some potential problem for the validity of the object? After all, it's called non-trivial for a reason.

Answer (score 0):

As far as the Standard is concerned, the constructor is not responsible for setting up the vtable. There is nothing responsible for setting up the vtable; vtables don't exist, as far as the Standard is concerned.

Rather, the vtable is a consequence of the *other* rules the compiler has to follow, relating to virtual function binding and such. So whether or not the constructor is called, the vtable's going to be set up *somewhere*, because otherwise the compiler will have trouble meeting its other obligations. That doesn't contradict the value-initialization rule; rather, it adds nuance to the practicalities of implementing the rule.

Comment: Maybe I shouldn't have used vptr as an example.  My point is, wouldn't skipping the call to a non-trivial constructor cause some potential problem?  After all, it's called non-trivial for a reason.

Comment: No, because the things which a non-trivial default constructor does are the same things which value-initialization does.

Comment: Quote from standard: "`A constructor is trivial if it is an implicitly-declared default constructor and if: - its class has no virtual functions (10.3) and no virtual base classes (10.1), and ...`". Though adding a virtual function will make an implicitly-declared default constructor change from trivial to non-trivial, it still does exactly the same thing (nothing more, nothing less), so skipping it doesn't hurt at all. Am I understanding correctly?

Comment: Yeah. The trivial/non-trivial definition *does* exist to address issues relating to vtable setup/teardown, but this particular exception to the special treatment of non-trivial constructors doesn't compromise compilers' ability to do their vtable duties.

Answer (score 0):

When a class `X` has no user-provided constructor, its default constructor does exactly what a constructor of the form `X::X() {}` would (`C++03[class.ctor]§6`). And as far as the standard is concerned, this is defined to perform default initialisation of all members and base class subobjects, *and nothing else.* So "calling the **generated** default constructor" is identical to "default-initialising all data members and base class subobjects."

So this actually does "less" than the value initialisation you quoted - as that value initialisation value-initialises all data members and base class subobjects. So it does all the constructor does, and more.

As far as implementation-specific things (like the vtable pointer) go, these are outside of the scope of the standard. It is a compiler's responsibility to make sure all of its implementation-specific mechanisms work regardless of constructor calls mandated by the standard.

Comment: The bolded part says `without an initializer`, but value-initialize does have an initializer: `()`.  As for vptr, maybe I shouldn't have used vptr as an example. My point is, wouldn't skipping the call to a non-trivial constructor cause some potential problem for the validity of the object? After all, it's called non-trivial for a reason.

Comment: Quote from standard: "`A constructor is trivial if it is an implicitly-declared default constructor and if: - its class has no virtual functions (10.3) and no virtual base classes (10.1), and ...`".  Though adding a virtual function will make an implicitly-declared default constructor change from trivial to non-trivial, it still does exactly the same thing, so skipping it doesn't hurt at all.  Am I understanding correctly?