# Confused by the difference about value-initializtion between C++ 11&14

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I read about value-initialization in http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization , but I'm really confused by the sample code below:

```
struct A {
    int i;
    A() {} // user-provided ctor, does not initialize i
};

struct B { A a; }; // no user-provided ctor

std::cout << B().a.i << '\n'; // value-initializes a B temporary
                          // leaves b.a.i uninitialized in C++03
                          // sets b.a.i to zero in C++11
// (note that B{}.a.i leaves b.a.i uninitialized in C++14, but for 
//  a different reason: C++14's B{} is aggregate-initialization)
```

cppreference says:

> In all cases, if the empty pair of braces {} is used and T is an aggregate type `that is not a class type with a default constructor (until C++14)`, aggregate-initialization is performed instead of value-initialization.

I think `B{}` should be value-initialized in C++ 11 because B has a default constructor(because of A).According to the rules about value-initialization:

> 2) If T is an non-union class type without any user-provided constructors, then the object is zero-initialized and then the implicitly-declared default constructor is called (unless it's trivial)
>   (since C++11)(until C++14)

So I think B{} should be zero-initialized first and then calls the default constructor. But unfortunatly, I compile the code with clang++, -std=c++11, the value of `B{}.a.i` is uninitialized. What's the problem?

Comment: The problem is that whoever wrote A is a moron and didn't initialize `i`. Seriously, you should not be relying on each user to initialize bits, your interface should never expose uninitialized data.

Comment: *"But unfortunatly, I compile the code with clang++, -std=c++11, the value of B{}.a.i is uninitialized"* It is quite likely that clang++ will implement proposed resolutions to DRs targeting C++11 even in C++11 mode. So I wouldn't be surprised if it used the C++14 rules for initialization (even in C++11 mode).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23745872/701092

Comment: I completely agree with Puppy.  F "the standard".  The real answer is "you must initialize i ... or risk undefined behavior sooner or later in your software's lifetime".

Comment: @Cu2S defect resolutions are considered to apply retrospectively

Comment: Agreeing with Puppy is pretty dangerous. In general.